# Jupyter Notebook in customised docker image is not launching

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have prepared the customised docker image with base image as `jupyter/scipy-notebook`. But after successfully building the docker image, when I am trying to run it then jupyter is not launching. I have attached the screenshot. I am not able to figure out what is missing and why. I have used `norebook.sh` to launch jupyter notebook. Codes are shown below:

`#!/bin/bash'`
# Strict mode
``` ``set ``` `-euo` `pipefail`

`IFS=$'\n\t'`

`# Set configuration defaults`
`: ${PASSWORD:=""}`
`: ${PEM_FILE:="/key.pem"}`
`: ${USE_HTTP:=0}`

`HASH=$(python -c "from IPython.lib import passwd; print(passwd('${PASSWORD}'))")
unset PASSWORD`

`if [ $USE_HTTP -ne 0 ]; then
  CERTFILE_OPTION=""`
`else`
`if [ ! -f $PEM_FILE ]; then
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $PEM_FILE -out $PEM_FILE \
      -subj "/C=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=dockergenerated/CN=dockergenerated"`
`fi`

`CERTFILE_OPTION="--certfile=$PEM_FILE"`
`fi`

`jupyter notebook \
    --port 8888 \
    --ip=0.0.0.0 \
    $CERTFILE_OPTION \
    --NotebookApp.password="$HASH" \
        --allow-root`

`unset HASH`

I have taken this script from [mayanlab/zika](https://github.com/MaayanLab/Zika-RNAseq-Pipeline/blob/master/notebook.sh) and made some changes as this script use very old versions of jupyter. I also tried with the IP address shown in screenshot as `127.0.0.1:8888`  and `localhost:8888` but nothing works. Kindly suggest.

.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the container on the host port `8887` (last command), so try `http://127.0.0.1:8887` in your browser.

The Port binding syntax in django is `-p host_port:container_port`, see e.g. [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)